# Group by sub array value and bring fields to main array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling to group by an array with it's sub-array. Here is my original array:

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    age: "20",
    car: {
      colour: "Blue",
      size: "Big",
      rpm: "380"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Mary",
    age: "21",
    car: {
      colour: "Orange",
      size: "Small",
      rpm: "20"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Janet",
    age: "22",
    car: {
      colour: "Blue",
      size: "Big",
      rpm: "380"
    }
  }
];
```

And I would like to group by the colour of the car object into this form:

```js
var cars = [
  {
    colour: "Blue",
    size: "Big",
    rpm: "380",
    people: [{ name: "Bob", age: "20" }, { name: "Janet", age: "22" }]
  },
  {
    colour: "Orange",
    size: "Small",
    rpm: "20",
    people: [{ name: "Mary", age: "21" }]
  }
];
```

I am relatively new to JavaScript so any help you can provide will be appreciated. Any external libraries are welcome.

**EDIT**
To answer @ths, I was able to successfully extract out the car object to the main array using this code:

```js
resultArray = [];

people.forEach(function(people) {
    let carObj = people.car;
    console.log("TCL: carObj", carObj)
    carObj["people"] = people;
    resultArray.push(carObj);
  });
```

But I had trouble combining the arrays into the different car types.

Comment: what did you done so far ?

Comment: What if the colors are the same but the size and rpm aren't?

Comment: @MrGeek, in my case the people are actually linked to the cars with some kind of a foreign key so it would not be possible for the colours to be the same but for the size and rpm different.
I am not sure how this array transformation would look like if they were different though.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    age: "20",
    car: {
      colour: "Blue",
      size: "Big",
      rpm: "380"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Mary",
    age: "21",
    car: {
      colour: "Orange",
      size: "Small",
      rpm: "20"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Janet",
    age: "22",
    car: {
      colour: "Blue",
      size: "Big",
      rpm: "380"
    }
  }
];

let carMap = {};

people.forEach(p => {
  const carKey = `${p.car.colour}-${p.car.size}-${p.car.rpm}`;
  
  if (carKey in carMap) {
    carMap[carKey].people.push({
      name: p.name,
      age: p.age
    });
  } else {
    carMap[carKey] = {
      ...p.car,
      people: [{
        name: p.name,
        age: p.age
      }]
    };
  }
})

console.log(Object.values(carMap));
```

Create a car-people Map. Define a carkey that combined by the attribute of car. Finally, get values of the carMap.

Answer (score 0):

The `.reduce` method can be used to transform arrays into objects with/arrays with a different structure:

```js
  var people = [
        {
            name: "Bob",
            age: "20",
            car: {
                colour: "Blue",
                size: "Big",
                rpm: "380"
            }
        },
        {
            name: "Mary",
            age: "21",
            car: {
                colour: "Orange",
                size: "Small",
                rpm: "20"
            }
        },
        {
            name: "Janet",
            age: "22",
            car: {
                colour: "Blue",
                size: "Big",
                rpm: "380"
            }
        }
    ];

    const generateId = (object) => Object.keys(object).map(key => key + object[key]).join('-');

    var personByCar = Object.values(people.reduce((acc, person) => {
        // Uniquely identify the car properties:
        const carId = generateId(person.car);
        // Add the people property to store related persons
        if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(carId)){
            acc[carId] = {...person.car, people: []};
        }
        // Add the person
        acc[carId].people.push({person});
        return acc;
    }, {}));

    console.log(personByCar)
```

More info about reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce